# How to analytically solve for $x$ in $x = e^{-1/x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

As the title goes, how do we analytically solve for $x$ in $x = e^{-1/x}$?

I attempted to differentiate then integrate and assumed c = 0, i get x = -2, but I am doubtful.

What would be the exact approach to solve this analytically?

Comment: Easy: with the elementary functions, you can't.

Comment: any way that is not elementary, that is just fine

Comment: What have you tried? People are more likely to answer your question if they can see you have put in some effort first

Comment: What is the meaning of "correct" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$-\frac1xe^{-1/x}=-1$$

and

$$-\frac1x=W(-1).$$

Comment: What is W(-1)? I have not seen this type of function before.

Comment: It is worth mentioning for the OP that $W$ here is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), a non-elementary function which comes about for solving exactly this type of problem, since it seems likely that the OP has never encountered this notation.

Comment: @JonesG Normal, it is not elementary.

Comment: It is worth noting that since the argument of $\operatorname{W}$
is less than $-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}}$, the equation does not have any real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x\to -1/z$ we get $-1/z=e^z$ hence $-1=ze^z$ hence $z=W(-1)$ hence
$$ x = -\frac1{W(-1)}$$
Where $W$ is [Lambert's function W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

The substitution is in order because $x=0$ is not a solution.